# Why my char array inside my struct is null even allocating the struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I've the following struct:

```
struct scp_header {
    char state_name[NAME_MAXSIZE];
    enum scp_packet_type type;
    size_t payload_size;
    size_t script_size;
};
```

I want to use this struct in several functions, but the first thing I need to do is to fill the field `state_name`, in order to do this, there is a part of my function which do the following:

```
struct scp_header *header;

if ((header = malloc(sizeof(struct scp_header)) == NULL))
    return -1;

if (header->state_name == NULL)
    printf("This field is NULL\n");
header->type = INIT;
header->payload_size = 0;
header->script_size = total_code_size;
```

I did the verification above, because when I tried to use `strncpy(header->state_name, "sometext", NAME_MAXSIZE)` I was getting a segmentation fault. So I decided to check if the `state_name` field weren't NULL and I'm really getting into the if statement that says that such field is `NULL`.

My question is: Why this field is `NULL` if I allocated the whole struct, it was supposed to `malloc` allocate the necessary memory to that field, wasn't it?

Comment: It's not NULL, as it has the the same address as came from malloc, so you must be doing something else.  The code you show here is incomplete and won't compile by itself, so you need to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's _not_ NULL [even if `header` were, it would still be non-null]. What you've done _should_ work unless `strlen("sometext")` is >= `NAME_MAXSIZE` [you'd have to ensure an EOS terminator with `header->state_name[NAME_MAXSIZE - 1] = 0;` Or, you could change `state_name` into: `char *state_name;` and do: `header->state_name = strdup("sometext");`

Comment: If you don't see an error message from the line starting `if ((header`, adjust your compiler settings before proceeding -- you have wasted a lot of time on an issue that the compiler can instantly diagnose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Ab)using parentheses this way is quite risky because you can easily trip.

`if ((header = malloc(sizeof(struct scp_header)) == NULL))`

Here, the result of the malloc call is compared to `NULL` (operator precedence, == has a higher precedence than =). When the malloc succeeds it returns a non-NULL value, the aforementioned comparison results in 0, which then gets assigned to `header`. The if-statement checks against `header` and would only return on `header` being non-zero.

FIX: `if ((header = malloc(sizeof(struct scp_header))) == NULL)`

But I strongly urge you to consider a more clear style.

Comment: One way to reduce `()`s: `if ((header = malloc(sizeof *header)) == NULL)`

Comment: Or just `if (!(header = malloc(sizeof *header)))`.